# Undefined symbols : how do I figure dependency resolution?

Tags: package-management, libraries, dependencies, slackware

I am trying to figure out how to handle the lack of dependency resolution in Slackware.

I installed Gnumeric from slackware.pkgs.org, but it won't run with a number of

> ** (gnumeric:10645): CRITICAL **: go_conf_[whatever]: assertion 'parent || key' failed

errors and eventually

> gnumeric: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/libspreadsheet-1.12.34.so: undefined symbol: gtk_widget_path_iter_set_object_name

According to `ldd`, no useful shared libraries are missing (to be sure I checked the output of `ldd` with `ls`).  However, two symbols are undefined :

```
$ ldd -r /usr/bin/gnumeric
[…]
undefined symbol: gtk_widget_path_iter_set_object_name  (/usr/lib64/libgoffice-0.10.so.10)
undefined symbol: gtk_widget_path_iter_set_object_name  (/usr/lib64/libspreadsheet-1.12.34.so)
```

I don't see any missing library if I run `ldd` on those two libs, but indeed I find a large number of missing symbols :

```
$ nm -D /usr/lib64/libgoffice-0.10.so.10|grep U|wc -l
1253
$ nm -D /usr/lib64/libspreadsheet-1.12.34.so|grep U|wc -l
2234
```

**Are there still some package missing, or do some installed package to be upgraded ?** (I'm guessing gtk+3) **And how do I find this out ?**

NB : I am not interested (yet) in automated tools to resolve dependencies (e.g. `slapt-get` or switching to Salix).

NB2 : FWIW, I managed to get Gnumeric working by installing the `gnumeric` and `goffice` packages provided by another contributor on slackware.pkgs.org, but obviously the generic question about how to find out what is missing and how to solve dependencies without testing all available packages combinations remains.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do it.

1) pkgs.org has a list of all required dependencies for a given package in the "Requres" section.

2) Download the source and compile it manually.  The ./configure or make will usually will flag missing libraries.  A quick google search will usually point you to the library source.